# Playing at/with cards

Tags: grammar

My teacher was talking about "playing cards" and he asked us what is correct. Is it "I'm playing cards"/"I'm playing with playing cards"/"I'm playing at cards"?

Comment: You can do all three, but they mean different things. "Playing cards" might involve a game of whist or bridge in a group. "Playing with cards" could be something a toddler does, or an older child trying to build a house of cards. "Playing at cards" is far less common, but could in a metaphorical sense be used for someone taking serious risks.

Comment: "We were playing **cards** / [a game of cards](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+game+of+cards%22&num=20&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNiKz1_PXcAhWGf5AKHehDAlgQ_AUIECgB&biw=1309&bih=619) / a [card game](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&biw=1309&bih=619&tbm=bks&ei=Ib13W87AE8uzwAT4lIH4CQ&q=%22a+card+game%22&oq=%22a+card+game%22&gs_l=psy-ab.12...0.0.0.3056.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.Z0TE2cEoRWg)."

Comment: @Mari-LouA  - please provide a dictionary definition of “play cards”. I couldn’t find any.

Comment: @user070221 "*playing cards*" is the same [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/460673/44619) that you gave, so I'm not sure why you left the comment.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  - in playing cards, playing is not a verb.

Comment: @user070221 We play **cards** (Present) We're playing **cards** (Present Continuous) the noun is the same. If this is b/c you think I downvoted your answer, I didn't. I can easily prove it if you want.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  - it is not a problem about up/downvotes. It is about understanding the question. This is apparently a GR one.

Comment: @user070221 so "now" it's a GR question but you felt it deserved an answer four hours ago. Pity. I already cast a vote to migrate the question to ELL, where it really belongs.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  - no, I said (please read) that it is apparently a GR, meaning it is not. There is no dictionary entry for “to play cards” anyway.

Comment: You can play bridge, poker, snap, go fish, blackjack.... these are all card games.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I think you should be aware that in French you say: “jouer ***aux*** cartes”, in Italian: “giocare ***a*** carte”. The question makes sense.

Comment: @user070221 I said the question belonged to ELL, who mentioned it being off-topic? Moreover, in English, you play football/tennis/basketball. The same "rule" applies with "cards" or with a card game.

Answer (score 3):

"Playing at cards" seems to be historical. It's not something most people would say, though you might encounter it in older books. Based on a [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=play%20cards%2Cplay%20at%20cards&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cplay%20cards%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cplay%20at%20cards%3B%2Cc0)  search, "play cards" seems to have overtaken "play at cards" as the preferred expression sometime around 1870.

In both expressions, "cards" is being used to mean some card game. (See [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/card), definition 3-2) That's why you won't find a definition for "play cards", because it's not one word, but rather "play" + [game], just like "play poker" or "play baseball".

"Play with cards" instead means to use the cards as a tool that you are playing with. This is the same as "play with a toy" or "play with fire". It is also correct, though less specific than the other expressions. The specific use of "playing with playing cards" is also fine, as this is just clarifying that the type of cards being played with are specifically [playing cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playing_card), rather than some other sort of card (such as business cards or baseball cards).

So as a single answer, all three are correct, but "play cards" is probably the best choice for most situations.